# What is the best way of selecting in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I select all images which **have** `data-original` attribute **without** `src` attribute?

I know : `$('img[data-original]:not(img[src])');`, but I think it is slow.

How can select it most efficiently?

Comment: I think that's the fastest you can go.

Comment: If you want to find the fastest way, then you will need to go to a site like jsperf.com and measure the performance of several different methods.  Measurement is the ONLY way to know which method is faster and you probably have to measure in multiple browsers to get the whole picture.

Comment: See http://jsperf.com/no-src-imgs.  Barmar's solution looks like the fastest jQuery method I tried.  Straight `querySelectorAll()` is quite a bit faster.  Which method is fastest also varies based on the number of images with each of the attributes because it is faster to filter out the largest number of items in the first part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to repeat `img`:

```
$('img[data-original]:not([src])')
```

I'm not sure how much difference it will make, though.